# Why wear sunglasses in indoor velodromes?

Tags: track-racing

I've watched a fair amount of UCI world cup track racing in the past year, and I've noticed most cyclists are wearing sunglasses in indoor velodromes.  Sometimes they're aerodynamic visors, but more often they are just standard sport sunglasses.  Why do track cyclists wear them?

Comment: Not going to use this as an answer but I wear shades in all wether when biking. Mainly to keep the wind out my eyes and any dust that may go in them.

Comment: This was my first thought: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlGetFM59dY

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Track cyclists are travelling in excess of 30mph.  At that speed you need eyewear to protect from the 'wind'.

Comment: Even as an amateur riding in a velodrome it's easy to get up fast enough to need eyewear.

Comment: @DavidW hopefully find that out myself soon enough - got a gift certificate for a taster session at Manchester velodrome :)

Comment: It's fun. I did a session at Newport not long ago. Glasses aren't strictly necessary if you're doing fairly short bursts (as you will in a taster session) but are nice to have

Comment: And even as an amateur, you _have_ to go fast enough to not fall down the banking.

Comment: Note that at certain tracks or levels of competition there can be local rules not permitting the use of darkened glass tints. When I raced I used contact lenses and wearing wrap style glasses helped to prevent the lenses from getting dry and flying out.

Comment: And the track isn't clean either, so there can for example be small shards of wood flying around.

Answer (score 4):

Track cyclists reach speeds over 50 km/h. At these speeds you need to cover your eyes and sunglasses look cooler than clear glasses. Because velodromes are usually well lit, they don't affect the cyclists sight.

Comment: When I went I also did some photography as we were a big group taking turns. "Well lit" is all relative

Comment: @ChrisH ain't that the truth!